# Cannot instantiate implementation type Repository`1[TDBContext]' for service type 'IRepository'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm hitting the error in the title when running this setup code:

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TDBContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("My"));

// Can't work out how to wire up the Repository?
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository>(p => new TDBContext());
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository), typeof(Repository<>));
//builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository), typeof(Repository<TDBContext>));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();

var app = builder.Build();  //ERROR HERE!
```

Service and Repository:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    
    public MyService(IRepository repository)
    {          
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
    
public class Repository<TDBContext> : IRepository where TDBContext : DbContext
{
    protected DbContext dbContext;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        dbContext = context;
    }
    public async Task<int> CreateAsync<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        this.dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        return await this.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    //.....
}


public class TDBContext : DbContext
{
    public TDBContext(DbContextOptions<TDBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyTransaction> Transactions { get; set; } = null!;

    public TDBContext()
    {
    }
}
```

I've tried a few suggestions found on here shown as code comments but no luck. Can someone please clarify how I wire up the Repository and get the DI to load in the DbContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the repository constructor. The container does not know how to handle `DbContext` as dependency when resolving the repository.

Did you mean to use the generic argument type instead?

Also the naming of the generic parameter might cause confusion.

```
public class Repository<TContext> : IRepository where TContext : DbContext {
    protected DbContext dbContext;

    public Repository(TContext context) {
        dbContext = context;
    }

    public async Task<int> CreateAsync<T>(T entity) where T : class {
        this.dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        return await this.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    //.....
}
```

And the registration will need to use the closed type

```
//...

builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository<TDBContext>>();

//...
```